# Abstract Generic Mocking - cannot instantiate proxy class of property?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to mock a fnction in a abstract generic class which has more abstract classes in it's constructor.

Here is the test:

```
        [Test]
        public void AbstractRepoTest()
        {
            var options = new Mock<DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext>>();
            var db = new Mock<CustomDbContext>(options);
            var repo = new Mock<BaseRepository<EntityBase>>(db);
            var service = new Mock<BaseService<EntityBase>>(repo, db);

            IQueryable<FactTableRevenue> theInfo = Enumerable.Empty<FactTableRevenue>().AsQueryable();

            repo.Setup(x => x.GetById("test")).Returns(theInfo);

            var abstractService = service.Object;

            Assert.AreEqual(theInfo, abstractService.GetById("test"));
        }
```

Here is the CustomDbContext contructor:

```
 public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

    }
```

Here is the BaseRepository constructor:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
        internal readonly CustomDbContext _db;

        public BaseRepository(CustomDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
     }
```

here is the BaseService constructor:

```
  public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : EntityBase
    {
        public DbContext _db { get; }

        public BaseRepository<T> _repository;

        public BaseService(BaseRepository<T> repository, DbContext db)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _db = db;
        }
    }
```

And here is the error code:

```
Tests.UnitTestService.AbstractRepoTest

Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Services.Services.BaseService`1[[Database.Common.E...

Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: Services.Services.BaseService`1[[Database.Common.EntityBase, Database, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
Moq.Mock`1[Services.Repositories.BaseRepository`1[Database.Common.EntityBase]]
Moq.Mock`1[Database.CustomDbContext.CustomDbContext]

   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Moq.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, IInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments) in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\ProxyFactories\CastleProxyFactory.cs:line 62
   at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance() in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock`1.cs:line 311
   at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject() in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock`1.cs:line 325
   at Moq.Mock.get_Object() in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock.cs:line 179
   at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object() in C:\projects\moq4\src\Moq\Mock`1.cs:line 283
   at Tests.UnitTestService.AbstractRepoTest() in C:\Users\USER\RiderProjects\REST\Tests\UnitTestService.cs:line 58
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems. I was mocking options ang giving it to my implementation of DbContext and I was not passing objects to the constructors rather than mocks.

I changed CustomDbContext by adding a empty constructor:

```
protected CustomDbContext(){}
```

And removed options and made implementations of the mock's:

```
            var db = new Mock<CustomDbContext>();
            var repo = new Mock<BaseRepository<EntityBase>>(db.Object);
            var service = new Mock<BaseService<EntityBase>>(repo.Object, db.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

The construction issue you have is most likely that you're passing the mock object (e.g., `db`) rather than the mocked object (e.g., `db.Object`) to the mock constructors.

```
var options = new Mock<DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext>>();
var db = new Mock<CustomDbContext>(options);
var repo = new Mock<BaseRepository<EntityBase>>(db.Object);
var service = new Mock<BaseService<EntityBase>>(repo.Object, db.Object);
```

Comment: Then I just get this error: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Probably haven't set up something on the mock? Debug it and work out where the null is, then ensure it's set up

Comment: After debugging for a while it seems like it is just mad that it is an refrence/mock and not a real object. I do not have a settup, the entire test is what you see here

Comment: You are setting up `GetById("test")` on the repository so there is more code here than what is needed to reproduce the problem you have. At a guess, because you're mocking implementations, there is a db context or repository member being accessed and it is not set up. I would consider mocking interfaces rather than implementations. If that isn't possible, consider using an in-memory db context as mocking a db context is hard and not recommended by microsoft.